# Why does multiplying 0 by negative double make it become -0?

Tags: c++

```
cout << 0 * -5 << endl; // this is zero
cout << 0 * -5.0 << endl; // this is negative zero
```

I'm new to c++, and I don't understand why multiplying by a double would affect zero times anything since it should always be zero.

Comment: Any sane set of rules that says that zero times anything is zero will also say that negative zero is equivalent to positive zero. So if this bothers you, you are using some strange, inconsistent set of rules.

Comment: Negative zero is a thing in the floating point world. Things get *weird* if you're not [prepared conceptually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line,

```
cout << 0 * -5 << endl;
```

both 0 and -5 are signed integers.  Integers do not distinguish between `0` and `-0`.

In the second line,

```
cout << 0 * -5.0 << endl;
```

the second number is a double, so the 0 gets promoted to a double as well, for which IEEE floating point defines both `0` and `-0` values.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the difference between computation of integers and doubles. First expression is done between two integers, but the second one is between two floating point numbers.